# Is there possibility how to use scribus module in python outside Scribus?

Tags: python, python-module, scribus

I would like to generate pdf files using `Scribus` and python scripting. I have been looking around and have found just examples of python scripts using scribus module within Scirbus. And commentary in these scripts, that

```
"This Python script is written for the Scribus scripting interface. 
It can only be run from within Scribus."
```

When I am using command

```
import scribus
```

In python, an error occurs `ImportError: No module named 'scribus'`. But when I am using this command within python console in `Scribus`, everything is ok and I can use this module. So, Where can I found this module?

Or can I run Scribus with input parametr as python script? Something like

```
scribus python_script.py
```

I am using both linux and windows, so solution in one of these os will be great.

`Python 3.3.2` & 
`Scribus 1.4.3`

Comment: The `scribus` module is implemented within Scribus, so you won't be able to use it with a standalone Python interpreter. You're much more likely to succeed with your second approach of trying to get Scribus to run a Python script using the command line.

Comment: Thank you. And do you know how to do that? I mean how to run Scribus with Python script as parameter to execute it?

Answer (score 3):

In fact you can pass a python script as argument to scribus.
But this works as far as I know only since version 1.5

Example from the [scribus wiki](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Command_line_scripts)

```
# only one short flag  + scribus doesnt open a document (the script itself does it)
scribus -py somescript.py --python-arg v
```

Answer (score 1):

Please have a look at the Scribus Documentation under

For Developers > Scripter API > Scripter Extensions

If you manage to write your functionality as "extension script", you can make Scribus execute it, on startup:

Scribus > File... > Preferences > Scripter > Enable Extension Scripts
and select your Script.

Now, if you run Scribus from the command line (not from the Python console), it should firstly run your script and do its magic.

---

Sorry, I did a longer search and could not find a way to send stuff from your Python console to your OS as if it were on the command line (I believe that would give you what you asked for). That would allow you to run your script (using Scribus) from your console.

Answer (score 0):

Use the command line interface as such:

```
python foo.py
scribus -ns -f myfile
```

The Python script simply runs Save as PDF programmatically(<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+P</kbd>) every few seconds.

**References**

- [Scribus Command Line Reference](http://www.scribus.net/svn/Scribus/trunk/Scribus/doc/en/cli.html)
- [Scribus Help:Manual Configprefs](http://wiki.scribus.net/canvas/Help:Manual_Configprefs)
- [Open source desktop publishing with Scribus](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-scribus/)
- [PyAutoGUI - Cross-platform module to control the keyboard](https://github.com/asweigart/pyautogui)